# I'm editing an application that loads data from a database, but it runs slower as it continues running

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

It's not a very well-designed application, but it gets the job done so it gets used. Over the past week, I've been making modifications to it. I've added and removed some features. It gets data from a SQL table. Depending on the run, sometimes this data can be upwards of 20,000 rows!

I was thinking about trying to get it to load only about 500 rows into the application at a time because when there are only 500 rows to process, it takes seconds, not minutes. I am working with pdfs, and that may be part of the issue too, but I figure this shouldn't be too hard to implement.

The thing is though, I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. My idea was to limit the query from 0 to 500, then increment this limit. The main loop however checks if the row returned is null. How do I know if the row returned is null because it's the last row of the table not the last row of the chunk?

Edit: I apologize. The query is quick. However, during the operations I do to pdf files, which is stored locally on the filesystem the application is running on, the speed of these operations gets slower. I was thinking the fact that I was pulling 20,000 rows of data into the application and having it loop through that locally was causing a slow-down. I may be wrong, but that is why I wanted to implement paging. Running the program on only 500 rows was very fast. They both pull in all of the rows at the start of the program then perform operations on PDFs using a library (i.e. placing this row data on the page). Each row corresponds to a page in the PDF, so the fact that the PDF is getting so large may also be slowing things down, but I will get paging working then report back. This is more of an application performance issue as time progresses.

Comment: Not enough information.  Are you using ADO.NET?  DataSets?  or IDataReaders?  Or something else?  Please show some code.

Comment: 20K rows is next to nothing for SQL Server. Should take about 2 seconds to pull it into a DataTable client-side.

Comment: So you have a "null" record as a placeholder at the end of your table?  We'd probably need to see how your data is laid out for this to make sense.

Comment: If you look at patterns used when paging, usually your query includes a subquery to get total number of rows, so if you get the next 100 rows, you will know if the last row has row_number == 1478 and the total items is 1478, then that must be the last row.

Comment: I normally keep a pointer (path) to big items like documents, PDFs, images, videos, and fetch the item from the file system when-needed rather than as part of the query's resultset.

Answer (score 2):

With the limited information I can only refer to some good SQL paging resource this is very commonly used technique by developers to limit the number of records retrieved.

There are tons on post you can find on internet.. [Here is one of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag as soon as your query is not returning 500 elements anymore and check for that flag in the main loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I failed to read the question carefully. The following is based on the *incorrect reading* that the individual PDFs were stored in the database. If significant amounts of data are not pulled from the database, then *please disregard this answer* as the slowness is likely caused by the PDF generator itself and can be easily verified with "commenting out adding pages". 20k reasonably sized records are nothing.

---

> The thing is though, I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. My idea was to limit the query from 0 to 500, then increment this limit.

Well, sort of (and ignoring possible new records being added or records being removed).

Here are the steps to one general approach. (It's not the only approach, but I'm highlighting it because it is a variant of the approach posed in the question and addresses the mentioned issue.)

1. Order the data (always when using view operations!)
2. Use LIMIT *and* OFFSET as implemented in the RDBMS. If an offset is not used, then the LIMIT increasing is effectively useless.
3. *When querying, LIMIT to one more row than desired per patch;* if you get LIMIT rows back, you're done. If you get LIMIT+1 rows back, need to issue another fetch as there are more records.
4. Increase the OFFSET by the LIMIT and loop until done.

In SQL Server use [OFFSET .. FETCH .. in ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

If rows can be added/removed during this process then additional considerations need to be taken into account to avoid phantom records and duplicating record processing. If such an issue is a concern, and it probably should be, I encourage prohibiting such operations - i.e. use a SERIALIZABLE transaction over the *entire* loop process - for simplicity.

---

An alternative to paging (and really, 20k records is *very few*) is to *only* load/use the larger "PDF"/BLOB columns on demand to reduce the memory pressure. Using memory isn't necessarily bad: but it *can* have severe performance impacts if allocations are pushed to swap or hot buffers are dropped.

Since we're talking about SQL Server the newer [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) type can be used instead of a BLOB for storing the PDF data. With a FILESTREAM column, SqlDataReader *doesn't* initially read the entire file/stream, but only obtains the "file pointer". Then, [the underlying file can be obtained on a per-item basis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx).

Such an approach can also be emulated with normal BLOB storage and careful selection of records (e.g. only fetch the "PDF"/BLOB when processing a particular record) or with external storage such as a filesystem (e.g. only store the "file path" in the database).

Because not all the data is always loaded, using an approach that delay-loads the large binary/BLOB data should mitigate the observed performance impact (if it is indeed related to memory pressure) and scale better (albeit by a constant factor): it may eliminate the need for paging entirely in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can always fetch a keyset in its entirety, and then your client can fetch the subsect of rows you need (first set of 500, second set of 500, third set... etc) by passing a subset of the keyset to a stored procedure, which can create a table from these keys and do an inner join.